# Mongodb Version mismatch Issue 3.6 to 4.0 upgrade

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, mongoose

I have installed the latest version of MongoDB i.e 4.0.10. I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

When i run `mongod --version` in putty command line i get version `4.0.10`

But When i run query in Studio3T `db.version();` i get version `3.6.3`

I ran  `dpkg -l | grep mongo` and got following output.

[image]

Please help me in identifying what i am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have two MongoDBs installed, judging from `3.6.3-0ubuntu1` installed by `apt`, and `4.0.10` versions there.

The page [Install MongoDB Community Edition on Ubuntu](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) stated:

> The `mongodb` package provided by Ubuntu is not maintained by MongoDB Inc. and conflicts with the `mongodb-org` package. To check if Ubuntu’s `mongodb` package is installed on the system, run `sudo apt list --installed | grep mongodb`. You can use `sudo apt remove mongodb` and `sudo apt purge mongodb` to remove and purge the mongodb package before attempting this procedure.

The older 3.6.3 appears to be still running in port 27017, thus that was the one connected to by Studio3T.

To ensure a clean installation, it's better to do a clean install by:

1. Follow the instructions in [Uninstall MongoDB Community Edition](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)
2. Remove 3.6.3 using `apt` as per the instruction above
3. Reinstall using the procedure in [Install MongoDB Community Edition on Ubuntu](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/).

It's probably not required to uninstall/reinstall everything again, but you don't want to have conflicting leftover files that will create problems down the road.

If you need the data in the old 3.6.3, please do `mongodump` before uninstalling it. You can subsequently restore it later.

Comment: Yes i completely uninstalled all the packages manually, then i have to kill the mongod process by PID. Then restarted mongod service which picked the right version.